# With code that opens a new page in an async method, do I need to run that on the main thread and if so how can I do this?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
  private async void GoalMgmt()
  {
     await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
     await _navigationService.OpenPageAsync<GoalsPage>();
  }

  public async Task OpenPageAsync<T>() where T : Xamarin.Forms.Page
  {
     var page = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
     await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page, false);
  }
```

As this is an async method I would like some advice on if this code should specifically be run on the main thread and if so then how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run code on the UI thread (or the mainthread) you should use the code below which forces the code to run on the MainThread.

Be aware that any async method 'could' have code running in any other thread as Xamarin sees fit.

There are some smart ways for the program to know if your code should run on the MainThread whe using async methods.

If you want to know the full ins and outs please check this article that my manager sent me:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                App.NavigationService.SetAsRoot(nameof(Views.StartPage));
            });
```

For calling async await methods:

```
 Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() =>
            {
                await App.NavigationService.NavigateTo(nameof(Views.StartPage));
            });
```

Comment: *"Be aware that any async method 'could' have code running in any other thread as Xamarin sees fit."* That's **over-broad**. As long as you don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` when do `await`, the code will stay on the same thread as the calling method. If it didn't, most UI-related code would be broken. Therefore, what matters is whether `GoalMgmt` was called while on UI thread, or not. If its only called from UI thread, there is no need to do `BeginInvoke`. Its fine to call `BeginInvoke..` to be safe, but be aware that **delays** the code inside slightly. Caller continues before it runs.